# Returning const reference to smart pointer vs using reference as parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

We use C++98 (older one).

Let's say we have a table and consider lookup. Ptr is some smart pointer.
Are the statements 1. - .3 below correct or both cases considered are equally safe/unsafe
from caller point of view?

Function prototype of lookup:

```
const Y::Ptr & lookup(const X::Ptr & x);
```

And the caller function where lookup is called:

```
const Y::Ptr & ret = lookup(x);
```

where x is an X::Ptr object or reference of the X::Ptr. So, we have the following usages based on the 2 lines above.

1. Function argument `const X::Ptr &`. This is normally safe and avoids copy constructor of `X::Ptr` when the function call is made. The caller is responsible for holding a reference of `X` for the object `X` to last through the duration of the lookup function call.
2. Return value `const Y::Ptr &`. This is not safe, because in the brief duration when this reference is on the stack, if the thread is interrupted/suspended and another thread deletes the entry from the table, both the Y object and the `Y::Ptr` object are deleted. As a result, the `Y::Ptr` reference on the stack refers to a Ptr object that is gone.
3. Local reference `const Y::Ptr &` to store the return value of lookup. This is not safe, for the similar reason of #2, but probably worse because of the scope of this local reference in the caller function is longer than the ref on the stack as the return value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got it about right.  A solution, clearly, is to return the smart pointer by value.  Note that your point #2 is completely subsumed by #3, so there's not much need to think about point #2 specifically (since there's no point having a reference you don't--or can't--use).

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on what `lookup` does, and what you are trying to
achieve.  Do you logically return a value, or a reference to
some internal data?  In a lot of cases of functions with names
like `lookup`, it is the latter, and it is often important that
the return value be a reference.  (An obvious case is
a function like `operator[]` in `std::vector`.)  Unless the
semantics require a reference, however, you are better off
returning by value.

Similar, at the call site.  If the caller needs a reference into
your data structure, he should declare the variable to be
a reference; otherwise, he should declare it to be a value.  (Of
course, if the function returns a value, there's never any
reasonable case where the local variable should be a reference.)

I think multithreading is a red herring here.  If other threads
are modifying the data structure `lookup` uses, you need
external synchronization, period.  If the function returns
a reference, and you keep it as a reference, then the critical
section includes the lifetime of the reference, but this is
generally not a big issue; if it is, the caller can store the
results as a value, and be done with it.

As a general rule, C++ prefers value semantics.  The language is
optimized with this in mind, including special rules to allow
the compiler to optimize out unnecessary copies.  Don't fight
it.  About the only exception would be using a reference to
`const` for function parameters.  (But even here, you want to be
consistent.  The ubiquitous convention is to pass class types by
reference to const, other types by value.  If this is the rule
used in your code, then use it systematically, without
exception.)

Comment: The question is not only reference vs value but rather which of two approached described in initial post is more safe.